# How do I speed up applying a function to a large pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

So I started yesterday on applying a function to a decent size dataset (6 million rows) but it's taking forever. I'm even trying to use pandarallel but that is not working well either. In any case, here is the code that I'm using...

```
def classifyForecast(dataframe):

    buckets = len(dataframe[dataframe['QUANTITY'] != 0])

    try:
        adi = dataframe.shape[0] / buckets
        cov = dataframe['QUANTITY'].std() / dataframe['QUANTITY'].mean()

        if adi < 1.32:
            if cov < .49:
                dataframe['TYPE'] = 'Smooth'
            else:
                dataframe['TYPE'] = 'Erratic'
        else:
            if cov < .49:
                dataframe['TYPE'] = 'Intermittent'
            else:
                dataframe['TYPE'] = 'Lumpy'

    except:
        dataframe['TYPE'] = 'Smooth'
    
    try:
        dataframe['ADI'] = adi
    except:
        dataframe['ADI'] = np.inf
    try:
        dataframe['COV'] = cov
    except:
        dataframe['COV'] = np.inf
    

    return dataframe

from pandarallel import pandarallel

pandarallel.initialize()

def quick_classification(df):
    return df.parallel_apply(classifyForecast(df))
```

Also, please note that I am splitting the dataframe up into batches. I don't want the function to work on each row, but instead I want it to work on the chunks. That way I can get the `.mean()` and `.std()` of specific columns.

It shouldn't take 48 hours to complete. How do I speed this up?

Comment: If that's literally your code, that's not how you use `apply`.  You are supposed to pass a function to `parallel_apply`, and that function will be called once for each row.  You are not PASSING the function, you are CALLING your function.  It will do its work in the normal method, then return a dataframe.  You then pass that dataframe to `parallel_apply`.  Who knows what that will do.

Comment: But your code won't work a row at a time.  Your `adi` and `cov` values need to apply to the entire dataframe.  Right?  But if that's the case, what is the rest of the code doing?  Maybe you should describe the problem in words.

Comment: How would you even know if it's working or not with those bare `except`s?

Comment: I know that it is working because I monitor the progress using `print` and a percentage of completion. I'm cutting the dataframe into parts by looking at the `cp_ref` column and using it to pull out unique data that is more than just one row at a time. I need it to apply the function to the dataframe in these chunks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `mean` and `std` are the only calculations here so I'm guessing that this is the bottleneck.

You could try speeding it up with `numba`.

```py
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit(parallel=True)
def numba_mean(x):
    return np.mean(x)

@njit(parallel=True)
def numba_std(x):
    return np.std(x)

cov = numba_std(dataframe['QUANTITY'].values) / numba_mean(dataframe['QUANTITY'].values)
```

Comment: Didn't speed it up much. It only has 6M rows. This shouldn't be taking long.